# Painting in blender

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

Any tips to avoid this distortion in blender?
Or should I use other software.

Comment: My first point to check would be the uv map, could you provide some more info to make it easier to find the problem. While more screenshots with at least the uv map and maybe info about modifiers on the object could help clear the situation, the .blend file would allow a more detailed inspection of the problem.

Comment: Yes, please include screen shots of your tool settings and the UV mapping, as well as indicate what kind of occlusion you are using. Also, have you tried painting in the Image Editor on the offending faces, and have you tried using Face Section Masking to isolate the problem areas and drop paint with the Fill tool?

Comment: Thank You for response I think I got the point for texturing this!